# google admin sdk retrieve chromebook hardware

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-admin-sdk, chromebook, google-apis-explorer, google-workspace

I need to retrieve hardware specification from all the provisioned Chromebooks and send it to a server.

I tried by developing an extension and deployed it through Google Admin but I will need to specify account id before sending it to the server.

I can create an option pop up for the extension but for accounts that have 1000 Chromebooks, it's not possible to input account id by going through each Chromebooks.

I recently stumbled into google admin SDK but this does not seems to have any way of retrieving Chromebook's hardware specification.

So my questions are:

- Can I push a configuration file to all Chromebooks so my extension
  can retrieve the account id.
- Can I retrieve Chromebook's hardware specification via Google Admin
  SDK?

Comment: Try using [Chromeosdevices](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/chromeosdevices) / [Directory API: Chrome Devices](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-chrome-devices) to retrieve all of an account's Chrome devices like serialNumber, firmwareVersion, model and other details.

Comment: Then try [Chromeosdevices: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/chromeosdevices/list) to retrieve a paginated list of Chrome OS devices within an account. Also, follow the authorization described in [Authorize requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing.html). Hope it helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot but my end goal is to retrieve hardware specification like processor, memory etc. and the API doesn't seems to retrieve those..